# python scrapy callback function err

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I have to crawl a lot of sites, is there any way?

my tried code gives an error in the callback-function, but I can't solve it. Is there any way to make my code usable, or to do the callback in a list format?

thank you.

```
import scrapy
from ..items import AppItem
urls = {
    'fun1': 'http://example1.com',
    'fun2': 'https://example2.com',
    # to add link
    # to add link ...
}

item = AppItem()


class Bot(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'app'

    def start_requests(self):
        for cb in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=urls[cb], callback=cb)
            

    def fun1(self, response):
        item['title'] = response.css('title')

        yield item

    def fun2(self, response):

        item['title'] = response.css('title')

        yield item
```

error

```
C:/Python310/python.exe c:/zCode/News/newsScraper/startApp.py
2021-11-26 03:09:06 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 129, in _next_request    
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "c:\zCode\News\newsScraper\newsScraper\spiders\app.py", line 18, in start_requests    
    yield scrapy.Request(url=urls[cb], callback=cb)
  File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 32, in __init__
    raise TypeError(f'callback must be a callable, got {type(callback).__name__}')
TypeError: callback must be a callable, got str
:  [<Selector xpath='descendant-or-self::title' data='<title>Daum</title>'>]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's an even easier solution by using loaders which takes into account the keys from the dict. This includes them, and you don't have to work with separate functions for each url.

```
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.item import Field
from itemloaders.processors import TakeFirst
import scrapy


class BotItem(scrapy.Item):
    objects = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())
    fun = Field(output_processor = TakeFirst())



class Bot(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'app'
    
    start_urls = {
    'fun1': 'http://example1.com',
    'fun2': 'https://example2.com',
    # to add link
    # to add link ...
}

    def start_requests(self):
        for keys,url in self.start_urls.items():
            yield scrapy.Request(
                url, 
                callback=self.fun1,
                cb_kwargs = {
                    'keys':keys
                })
            

    def fun1(self, response, keys):
        item = response.xpath('//div[@class="container"]')
        for stuff in item:
            l = ItemLoader(BotItem(), selector = stuff)
            l.add_value('fun', keys)
            l.add_xpath('objects', '//div[@class="some_objects"]//test()')
            yield l.load_item()
```

Answer (score 0):

As the exception says, you are passing a string as callback while a callable is expected.

That means doing this instead would work:

```py
    def start_requests(self):
        for cb in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url=urls[cb], callback=self.fun1)
```

Since you are providing your urls and the callback you want to use in code anyway I'd suggest that you just drop your `urls` dict and yield your requests directly without the loop:

```py
    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url='http://example1.com', callback=self.fun1)
        yield scrapy.Request(url='http://example2.com', callback=self.fun2)
        ...
```

That would at least be the easiest solution.
If you insist on calling the methods as string, you'll probably need to work with `getattr`. For that purpose, check [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061/calling-a-function-of-a-module-by-using-its-name-a-string)